# How to calculate defined limit using l'Hospital's rule?

Tags: limits

I want to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+2x)^{2/(3x+1)} $$

It is clear to see that by plugging the value $x=0$ the result is 1. I want to calculate the limit using L'Hospital's rule, by applying $a^x=e^{x\ln(a)}.$ I got :

$$e^{2\ln(1+2x)/(3x+1)}$$

Then I tried to calculate the power limit by using l'Hospital's rule, and eventually calculate e^(power limit answer). still could not find the correct answer that way. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit is 1. No l’Hospital needed.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that but my task is solving it by using lh'opitals rules

Comment: @user451803 This cannot be solved with L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @user451803 If you are ok, you can set as solved. One of the right one I mean. Thanks!

Comment: @user451803 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

let $y$ = $(1+2x)^{2/(3x+1)}$

$ln$ $y$ = $\frac{2}{(3x+1)}$ $ln$ $(1+2x)$

taking the limit then take the Exponential $e$ of the answer

is that what you do ?!

because  its not $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ the answer will be vary So ,

$\lim_{x\to0}$ $\frac{4}{3(2x+1)}$ apply L'H again to get $\lim_{x\to0}$ $\frac{0}{6}$ = 0

$e^{0}$ = 1

Comment: Yeah exactly, Thank you for assisting me.  Thanks everybody who answered on here.

Comment: This is not correct on all cases. LHospitals rule is meant for undetermined forms.

Comment: But i think it's just a practical question to use the exponential Technic for solving other questions @Rebellos

Answer (score 3):

L'Hospital's rule works for limits of the form :

$$\frac{0}{0}$$

$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$

etc, which are called undetermined forms.

You cannot apply it on other cases, the limit of the derivatives of the denominator and numerator will **not** be the same as the limit of the initial expression.

As you've mentioned, this is a straight-forward limit to calculate, so :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1+2x)^{2/(3x+1)} = 1$$